# Moving average failure without static storage

Tags: c, static

Code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getAverage(int i, int array[]);

int main(void)
{
    int array [] = {45, 42, 41, 40, 43, 45, 46, 47, 49, 45}; //not working
    static int array [] = {45, 42, 41, 40, 43, 45, 46, 47, 49, 45}; //works fine
    int i, average = 0; 

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(int); i++)
        average = getAverage(i, array);
    printf("Promedio: %d\n", average);

    return 0;
}

int getAverage(int i, int array[])
{
    int c = (array[i]+array[i+1])/2;
    return c;
}
```

My question is because it gives me results incorrect If I remove the **static** of array. Why this happens?

**Update**

```
int main(void)
{
    int array [] = {45, 42, 41, 40, 43, 45, 46, 47, 49, 45};
    int i, average = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(int) - 1; i++)
        average = (1 * array[i]) + (1.0 - 1) * average;
    printf("Promedio: %d\n", average);

    return 0;
}
```

I did this with the formula of the Wikipedia

Comment: About your update: 1) `1` is the multiplicative identity element, thus superfluous. 2) What do you think will `(1.0 - 1) yield? (hint: the `int` value `1` is converted to `double`, i.e. the same type as `1.0`). Please get the mathematics right and test your code before posting/further editing. If you are **really** lost, have a look at the mathematics site; they might help you with that - please read tieir FAQ beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing out of bounds of your array on the last call to the function. `array[i+1]` will be off the end when `i` is the last index.

This causes undefined behaviour. When undefined behaviour is triggered, anything can happen.

Comment: @Tony "anything can happen" literally means anything.  Appearing to work is one of those things.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking *undefined behaviour* as you access your array past the last element:

```
array[i]+array[i+1]
```

What if `i` is at the last valid index?

The `static` did not correct this, but just apparently hid the effect. That was plain coincidence and in **no way** related to `static`.

Note that you are in no way calculating the [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)/[media móvil](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_m%C3%B3vil). You just calculate the average of two neighbouring values (`array[i]`, `array[i+1]`). And as your `printf` is outside the loop, you just print the last result - which is the last element and the forbidden memory afterwards).

Comment: How you can avoid this? Well, count one less in the loop.

Comment: @Tony, No offence, but please work on your English I think I already gave you some hints in my comments.

Comment: For the formulas: please read the Wikipedia articles or other resources about the mathematical background; they are not that complicated and I posted the Spanish link (I presume that is your language according to your code). As you brought up the subject, you should get into this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop factor `i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)`, you will set i the last valid index of the array, and then in the `getAverage` function you access `array[i+1]` which is out of the array's bound. This lead to undefined behavior.

By the way, your only output is the average of the last two numbers, I wonder if your purpose is to print the average of each two numbers or the whole array.

Comment: The for loop does not acccess anything. It just calculates the index.

Comment: In your for loop you call the `getAverage` function which would access out of your defined array.

Comment: It is not **my** for-loop, as I'm not the OP. And the function you mentioned in the 2nd half of the sentence; the first part clearly refers to the loop-construct. It's just you should get the phrases right. "access" is a very important term with regard to UB and the location it occurs is exactly the point here.

Comment: @Olaf sorry, I didn't notice you are not the one who ask the question, I would correct this :)